# Change ssh username and password

Tags: apache-2.2, centos

I use CentOs 5.4 Operating System.
Suppose my web server is 'xyz.com' and document root is '/var/www/html/'.

How can i change ssh username and password of my web server?

Comment: why does the domain or documentroot come into it ? Are you serving pages from home directories ?

Comment: What does Apache httpd have to do with the question?

Answer (score 3):

You can change the login credentials for your user with `usermod -l $NEW_LOGIN $USERNAME` (for changing the user name) and `passwd $USERNAME` (for changing the password). You'll need superuser privileges to perform these actions.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not so clear!

Anyway, you can change the Linux user password using the passwd command after you login using the username you want to change its password.

```
$ passwd
```

You can change any user password using:

```
$ sudo passwd <username>
```

Usernames are not usually changed! You can create new users!